# How to pass type from typename to GetExports in MEF?

Tags: .net, mef

I have created a CompositionContainer, and now instead of giving the types explicitly I want to get the exports by using the names of the types.

The code below is working fine:

```
var p1Value = p.Container.GetExports<IPlugin, IPluginData>()
    .First(ip => ip.Metadata.Param.Equals(
        args[1],
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Value
    .Execute(args.Skip(1).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(p1Value);
```

But I want to achieve same thing if I have two string variables containing "IPlugin" and "IPluginData". Is there any way to pass the types by name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveat: this isn't the normal way to use MEF. But since you asked... you can use the [overload of GetExports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833158.aspx) which accepts an [ImportDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.importdefinition.aspx).

To discover which contract name you have to use for a given type, you can call `AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(typeof(IPlugin))`. Typically it is just the full type name.

The exact metadata type is not important - all that matters are the metadata properties declared on it. You can describe these as in the `requiredMetadata` dictionary below.

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

string contractName = "SomeNamespace.IPlugin";
var requiredMetadata = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
requiredMetadata["Meta1"] = typeof(string);
requiredMetadata["Meta2"] = typeof(int);

var importDefinition = new ContractBasedImportDefinition(
   contractName,
   null,
   requiredMetadata,
   ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore,
   false,
   true,
   CreationPolicy.Any);

var exports = container.GetExports(importDefinition);
Console.WriteLine(exports.Count());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Hi Wim, this is working, But as you said its not normal way to use MEF, could you plase put an example of whats normal and good way?  What I am doing is creating DirectoryCatalog because I am copying all plugins to bin folder of the project, now I want to use type by its name and metadata and use it. Would please you suggest me any good way to achieve that?

Comment: @RAJ: why do you need to do this by type name? That's the part I'm worried about. Normally you have a consumer with `[Import]` or `[ImportMany]` attributes, and this consumer expects a certain type like `IPlugin`. If you don't have this type in advance, then how are you going to use the imported object(s)?

Comment: Wim, the reason is I am creating some components which are composed in a console application, so I can pass commands to my utility. Console app will be able to accept different command (one is IPlugin, other may by IImportFile, IExportFile etc) served by different contracts in the application. Thats whole ides behind it.

Comment: Well, if your console app is invoked like `myconsoleapp mycommand arg1 arg2 ...` and you want to be able to plug in extra commands, then you only need an `[ImportMany]` of `IEnumerable<Lazy<ICommand,ICommandMetadata>>`. The metadata should have a "Name" property so that you can match the `"mycommand"` string to a specific command plugin that was imported. Once you have selected the right command based on the metadata, you can just invoke `ICommand.Execute(args)`. I don't see a reason to depend on type names anywhere.

Comment: That was only my initial approach, but then thought that there can be a different contract composed too. I was just trying to make it more sophisticated. But I agree using IEnumerable<Lazy<ICommand, ICommandMetaData>> and find type based on metadata. So all the commands can now have common interface and no need of finding type at runtime.

Comment: According your doubt regarding using type names: I'm using string type names to resolve objects when deserializing some settings from xml.